# Cannot get IronPython Console in PyDev to resolve System.String methods

Tags: pydev, ironpython

I'm using `IronPython 2.7` within `PyDev 4.0.0.2x` in Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2).  The editor's Autocompletion can 'see' the `IsNullOrEmpty` method in `System.String` library, but the Console cannot (opened against IronPython OR the current Script in the editor).  It's not just autocompletion at that point, it throws an exception when I do this in the console:

```
import clr
import System
System.String.IsNullOrEmpty("")
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  AttributeError: 'type' object has no attribute 'IsNullOrEmpty'
```

I have no troubles in an ipy.exe terminal outside of Eclipse/PyDev. Following the help file, I checked the dump from `eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_4.0.0.201504132356\pysrc>ipy.exe interpreterInfo.py`.  Interestingly, all the `.NET` libraries are missing from the `forced_lib` section of the output, though they are there by default in my configured ironpython interpreter.  I'm not sure if this is related.

UDPATE:
I added System.String to the forced builtins of the IronPython interpreter configured for PyDev, updated and restarted the Workspace == No difference.
I can call 'import System.String' without issues, but when I call 'from System.String import *, I get an interesting error of "ImportError: no module named str".  I proceeded to create a System.String via: 'v = System.String("v")'.  When I called dir(v), I only see python functions for python strings - nothing for .NET strings.  I did not have this issue in PVTS for VS2013